# SQL Server DELETE error - Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I having an error when trying to delete rows using a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM tblOrderDetails
WHERE  ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM tblProducts WHERE Discontinued = 1)
```

The error which I understand is:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I know the subquery is returning several values, but how can I then delete those rows
Thanks any help would be appreciated.
Patrick

Comment: You can't use the `=` operator to check whether something's in a list - have a go with with the `IN` keyword

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM tblOrderDetails 
WHERE ProductID IN (
    SELECT ProductID 
    FROM tblProducts 
    WHERE Discontinued = 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `in`:

```
DELETE FROM tblOrderDetails WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM tblProducts WHERE Discontinued = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 DELETE OD
 FROM tblOrderDetails AS OD
 INNER JOIN tblProducts as P ON P.ProductID =OD.ProductID 
 WHERE P.Discontinued = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

IN will allow you to define a set the should be deleted and not a single row.

```
DELETE FROM tblOrderDetails WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM tblProducts WHERE Discontinued = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE 
  FROM tblOrderDetails
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM tblProducts AS T2
                WHERE T2.ProductID = tblOrderDetails.ProductID
                      AND T2.Discontinued = 1
              );
```

But what do the auditors think about the loss of historical data for now discontinued products...?